# Zxing scanner Camera zoom

Tags: java, android, camera, zooming, zxing

I've been trying to solve the problem for 3 days, but I still have not found the answer. 
I want to add a ZOOM to the camera while scanning the qrcode through the Zxing scanner.

build.gradle:

```
   implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
```

Xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

ScannerFragment:

```
    @Override
       public void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         activateScanner();
     }

   private ViewGroup contentFrame;
   private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;

    private void activateScanner() {
    if(zXingScannerView != null) {

        if(zXingScannerView.getParent()!=null) {
            ((ViewGroup) 
     zXingScannerView.getParent()).removeView(zXingScannerView); // to 
      prevent crush on re adding view
        }
        contentFrame.addView(zXingScannerView);

        if(zXingScannerView.isActivated()) {
            zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
        }

        zXingScannerView.startCamera(camId);
        zXingScannerView.setFlash(isFlash);
        //zXingScannerView.setAutoFocus(isAutoFocus);
    }
}
```

I added SeekBar And with it I want to control the zoom of the camera.

```
private Camera cameraZoom;
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

   try { 
       Camera.Parameters parameters = cameraZoom.getParameters(); 
   } 
   catch (NullPointerException e) { 
       Log.d("NullP",e.getMessage()); 
   }
}
```

LOG:

```
D/NullP: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference
```

I tried to do this using the code above, but there were only errors

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Would you please provide the error logs ?

Comment: _E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference_   I don't know how to properly initialize the camera.

Comment: Something related to your question https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/259

Comment: Search the method setZoom() in the following file for reference
https://github.com/srowen/zxing-bsplus/blob/master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationUtils.java

Comment: @ViVekH,  public static void setZoom(Camera.Parameters parameters, double targetZoomRatio)  In this method, there is the item Camera.Parameters parameters. Where can I get this parameters when calling the method? If I do as in my example : 
     // Camera cameraZoom;
     // Camera.Parameters parameters = cameraZoom.getParameters (); 

there will be an error

Comment: try importing android.hardware.camera2, but as mentioned here  github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/259 i doubt you will be able to get the camera instance that zxing has, anyways worth a try.

Comment: Do you have error as the activity/fragment loads or you have no problem unless you change the SeekBar ? if it happens on page load, put cameraZoom.getParameters() in a NullPointerException try block and see what happens, let us know what was the result please

Comment: @Joe , try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = cameraZoom.getParameters();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.d("NullP",e.getMessage());
        }

Log: D/NullP: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Joe, Yes, the error occurs when you change the SeekBar, because the camera's object is not initialized and I do not know how to do it correctly.

Comment: The code you have provided is not enough to answer bro, please provide the most of your code dealing with zXingScanner or camera

Comment: @Joe, I updated my post and added more code, please see.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cameraZoom == null){    
     cameraZoom = Camera.open(); 
}
```

This line is missing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the camera when Zxing is opening the camera, so cameraZoom.getParameters () (cameraZoom is null).